# Подскажите как ограничить вывод элементов в php

Tags: php, joomla

Часть кода отвечает за вызов тегов в списке статей. Как задать, чтобы выводилось к примеру максимум 5 тегов. Спасибо

```
<?php 
$tags = K2ModelItem::getItemTags($item->id);
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($tags); $i++) {
    $tags[$i]->link = JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getTagRoute($tags[$i]->name));
}
   $item->tags=$tags;     ?>
   <?php if(count($item->tags)): ?>
   <!-- Item tags -->

    <?php foreach ($item->tags as $tag): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $tag->link; ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: кошмар какой то

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В for-цикле следует поправить условие завершения цикла, добавив условие `$i < 5`

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($tags) && $i < 5; $i++) {
  ...
}
```

Или модифицировать метод `K2ModelItem::getItemTags()`, так что бы он принимал дополнительный необязательный параметр, ограничивающий выборку

```
function getItemTags($id, $limit = null) {
  ...
}
```

Тогда можно будет, ограничивать любым количеством элементов

```
$tags = K2ModelItem::getItemTags($item->id, 5);
```

Затем в цикле foreach, добавьте выход по такому же условию

```
 <?php $counter = 0; ?>
 <?php foreach ($item->tags as $tag): ?>
   <?php if (++$counter > 5) break; ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $tag->link; ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Попробовал оба метода. Ни один не сработал.

Comment: @Ivan дополнил ответ